# Question regarding the ADC MCP3201 interfacing with PIC16F72 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc, load-cell, pic16f

I provide the 1.2 MHz clock to SCK pin to the ADC from PIC clock pin, but how I can receive the data from MCP3201 ADC, which provides a 12 bit binary data on SPI pin SDI of PIC? Buffer of PIC is 8 bit so how I can receive the extra 4 bits from ADC?

---

I will share you my C code. Please check and suggest me where I can modify the code.

```c
#include <xc.h>
#include <PIC16F72.h>
#include "config.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#define SS RA5
/***************INITIALIZING LCD MODULE**************************/
#define Data_PORT PORTB
#define Enable_pin RC6
#define RS RC7
#define CTRL_PORT_DIR TRISC
#define DATA_PORT_DIR TRISB
int LSB=0,MSB=0,FINAL_DATA=0;
/*****************************************************************/
void lcd_init(void);
void LCD_command(unsigned char command);
void LCD_data(unsigned char data);
void WriteStringToLCD(const char *s);

/**********************initiAslizing SPI*****************************/
void SPI_Initialize_Master();
unsigned SPI_Ready2Read();
char SPI_Read();
/****************************************************************/
int VALUE;

void main(void)
{
   
   SPI_Initialize_Master();
   __delay_ms(150);
   
   LCD_command(0x01);
   lcd_init();
   const char msg[] = "ADC_VALUE=";
   char a= 0x30;
   LCD_command(0x80);
   WriteStringToLCD(msg);
   while(1)
   {  
        VALUE = ADC_READ();
        LCD_command(0x8A);
        LCD_data(VALUE);
        __delay_ms(500);
   }
       
}
  


void lcd_init(void)
       {
        CTRL_PORT_DIR = 0x00;                           /* Direction of control port as Output                      */
        DATA_PORT_DIR = 0x00;                           /* Direction of data port as Output                         */
        LCD_command(0x38);                              /* LCD command - 5x7 matrix                                 */
        LCD_command(0x80);                              /* LCD command - Force cursor to the bigining of first line */
        LCD_command(0x3C);   // activate 2nd line
        LCD_command(0x0C);                              /* LCD command - Display ON, cursor OFF                     */
        LCD_command(0x01);                              /* LCD command - Clear display                              */
        }
void LCD_command(unsigned char command)
{
    RS=0;
    Data_PORT=command;
    Enable_pin=1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    Enable_pin=0;
}


void LCD_data(unsigned char data)
{
    RS=1;
    Data_PORT=data;
    Enable_pin=1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    Enable_pin=0;
}

void WriteStringToLCD(const char *s)
{
    while(*s)
    {
        LCD_data(*s++);   // print first character on LCD
    }
}


void SPI_Initialize_Master()
{
     TRISC5 = 0; // SDO pin set as output pin for data out
     TRISC4 = 1; // SDI pin set as data in pin s
     TRISC3 = 0; // SCK pin Set as output 
     TRISA5 = 0; // SS pin set as output pin for slave select
     TRISB = 0x00;
     SSPSTAT = 0b00100000; // data transmittend on falling edge of clock cycle
     SSPCON = 0b00100001; //pg 75/234  idle state for clock is low level & fosc/16 
     SS = 1;
    
}

int ADC_READ(void)
{
       SS = 0;
       SSPBUF = 0x01; // Initiate SPI bus cycle
       SSPSTATbits.BF = 0; // CLEAR THE BUFFER BIT
       while(!SSPSTATbits.BF);
       __delay_ms(10);
       MSB = SSPBUF;
       __delay_ms(10);
       
       SSPBUF = 0x81; // Initiate SPI bus cycle
       SSPSTATbits.BF = 0; // CLEAR THE BUFFER BIT
       while(!SSPSTATbits.BF);
       LSB = SSPBUF;
       __delay_ms(10);
       SS = 1;   
       
       LSB=(LSB>>1);
       MSB=(MSB<<7);
       FINAL_DATA = MSB+LSB;
       return(FINAL_DATA);
}
```

Comment: You did read the [ADC's data sheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21290F.pdf), didn't you? Chapter 6 has a lot to say according to 8-bit SPI transfers. What specifically is not clear? -- Don't use the PIC's system clock for SPI transfer, use the SCK pin.

Comment: in the above code i was provides the 16 clocks (two 8bit 8bit) but in this case when i apply pressure on load cell some unknown data was shown on the osciloscope.but in 2nd clock cycle remain constant no change at this point.and also give me ans,adc mcp3201 having in+ and in- pins i was connected green wire of load cell to in+ and white to in- so this connection is ok or not.

Comment: @AmolGholap make sure an answer is an answer, when you have rep you can comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the datasheet! It answers your question exactly. Here is a direct quote:

> With most microcontroller SPI ports, it is required to clock out eight
> bits at a time. If this is the case, it will be necessary to provide
> more clocks than are required for the MCP3201. As an example, Figure
> 6-1 and Figure 6-2 show how the MCP3201 device can be interfaced to a
> microcontroller with a standard SPI port.

[image: timing diagram from datasheet]

Datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21290f.pdf

There's more information in there on the subject that I have not quoted.